# Python Predicting temperature via Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The US National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) operates thousands of climate observation stations (mostly in the US) that collect information about local climate.  Among other things, each station records the highest and lowest observed temperature each day.  These data, called "Quality Controlled Local Climatological Data," are publicly available [here](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/orders/qclcd/) and described [here](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/quality-controlled-local-climatological-data-qclcd).

`temperatures.csv` contains an excerpt of that dataset.  Each row represents a temperature reading in Fahrenheit from one station on one day.  (The temperature is actually the highest temperature observed at that station on that day.)  All the readings are from 2015 and from California stations.

Suppose you're planning a trip to Yosemite for Christmas break this year, and you'd like to predict the temperature on December 25. Use predict_temperature to compute a prediction for a temperature reading on that day.

I'm working on this problem using Python Jupyter Notebook.

```
import numpy as np
from datascience import *

# These lines do some fancy plotting magic.
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', FutureWarning)
PREDICTION_RADIUS = 7
```

Let us solve that problem. We will convert each date to the number of days since the start of the year.
In [72]:

```
def get_month(date):
    """The month in the year for a given date.

    >>> get_month(315)
    3
    """
    return int(date / 100)
​
def get_day_in_month(date):
    """The day in the month for a given date.

    >>> get_day_in_month(315)
    15
    """
    return date % 100
​
DAYS_IN_MONTHS = Table().with_columns(
    "Month", np.arange(1, 12+1),
    "Days in Month", make_array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31))
​
# A table with one row for each month.  For each month, we have
# the number of the month (e.g. 3 for March), the number of
# days in that month in 2015 (e.g. 31 for March), and the
# number of days in the year before the first day of that month
# (e.g. 0 for January or 59 for March).
DAYS_SINCE_YEAR_START = DAYS_IN_MONTHS.with_column(
    "Days since start of year", np.cumsum(DAYS_IN_MONTHS.column("Days in Month")) - DAYS_IN_MONTHS.column("Days in Month"))
​
def days_since_year_start(month):
    """The number of days in the year before this month starts.

    month should be the number of a month, like 3 for March.

    >>> days_since_year_start(3)
    59
    """
    return DAYS_SINCE_YEAR_START.where("Month", are.equal_to(month))\
                                .column("Days since start of year")\
                                .item(0)
​
# First, extract the month and day for each reading.
with_month_and_day = temperatures.with_columns(
    "Month", temperatures.apply(get_month, "Date"),
    "Day in month", temperatures.apply(get_day_in_month, "Date"))
# Compute the days-since-year-start for each month and day.
fixed_dates = with_month_and_day.apply(days_since_year_start, "Month") + with_month_and_day.column("Day in month")
# Add those to the table.
with_dates_fixed = with_month_and_day.with_column("Days since start of year", fixed_dates).drop("Month", "Day in month")
with_dates_fixed

def predict_temperature(day):
    """A prediction of the temperature (in Fahrenheit) on a given day at some station.
    """
    nearby_readings = with_dates_fixed.where("Days since start of year", are.between_or_equal_to(day - PREDICTION_RADIUS, day + PREDICTION_RADIUS))
    return np.average(nearby_readings.column("Temperature"))
```

I tried to solve the bug:

```
Christmas_prediction = predict_temperature(days_since_year_start(12) + 25) 
Christmas_prediction
```

But it gives me an error. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: That is puzzling. Is there a line number or stack trace associated with the SyntaxError?

Comment: If you are getting a syntax error, print the whole stack-trace and maybe a snippet of the relevant part of your code. Remove all this irrelevant information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this question by running in Jupyter notebook.